# Using Javascript to pick a random city

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to make a javascript program that will pick a departure and arrival city for imaginary flights. I've tried to go about it a couple different ways, I have this so far, but its still not working...(this is just for the arrival city)

Arrive

```
    <p id = "arrival"></p>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function arriveRandom() {
        var arv  = ["Houston" , "Atlanta" , "Honolulu" , "Paris"];
        var dept = ["Atlanta" , "Salt Lake City" , "Kennedy Intl" , "Los Angeles" , "San Fransisco"];
        var randArv = randomGenerator(0, arv.length);
        var item = array[randArv]

        document.getElementById("arrival").innerHTML = "item";

        }
```

Comment: Where is your `randomGenerator()` function? What are the results that you get?

Comment: well for one, `randomGenerator()` is not defined anyhwhere

Comment: I believe in the last line, `"item"` should actually be `item`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.random();`

```
function arriveRandom() {
    var arv  = ["Houston" , "Atlanta" , "Honolulu" , "Paris"];
    var dept = ["Atlanta" , "Salt Lake City" , "Kennedy Intl" , "Los Angeles" , "San Fransisco"];
    var randArv = arv[Math.round(Math.random()*(arv.length-1))];
    var randDept = dept[Math.round(Math.random()*(dept.length-1))];

    // now randArv and randDept have random arrivals and departures
    }
```

edit: thanks to Robert Contardo Wirth. He pointed out that my random number actually is not an integer. Add Math.round() as he suggested and this should work fine.

Comment: I think it should be `(* arv.length - 1)`, as arrays are zero-indexed (?)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sam Creamer's response I think [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) should be used to get an integer. Example:

```
var randArv = arv[Math.round(Math.random()*(arv.length-1))];
```